# Container a=new getContentPane()

Tags: java

What is mean 'Container a=new getContentPane()" ?

Answer (score 2):

Container a=new getContentPane()" wouldn't compile...

getContentPane() is a method of javax.swing.RootPaneContainer.

Container a = getContentPane() would get the contentPane of the component.

[This part](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) of the Swing tutorial talks about panes a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is valid code. According to [this Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), the `new` keyword requires a constructor call as its argument, i.e. something like `Rectangle()`; a class name followed by a list of arguments (optional). Your code doesn't have this, instead it has a regular method call.

Comment: Technically, nothing prevents you from having a class named "getContentPane"

Answer (score 0):

A variable named 'a' of type Container is declared and assigned a new Object of class getContentPane.

Since 'getContentPane' violates the Java naming conventions for classes (which ascribe a capitalized first letter) and is also a prominent method name in Swing frames, it's probably a mistake and results in a compiler error.

Try removing the "new" to call the method rather than constructing an object.